# MNE read EEG channel location from EEGLAB set file

Tags: eeglab, mne-python

I have imported a set file from EEGLAB using io.read_epochs_eeglab. I am now computing the channel connectivity matrix to perform a cluster permutation. Since for EEG data it is still not possible to use the template that corresponds to my net (GSN-HydroCel-128), I am using mne.find_ch_connectivity. What I am trying to understand is how the channel coordinates of the set file are interpreted by MNE. Is the order of X, Y and Z coordinates the same? And the unit of measure? I wonder if I should create a separate info with opportunely arranged coordinates or everything is correctly computed in an automatic way. Many thanks!